# Drag and drop functionality in pyqt5 with custom widgets, creates widgets with contents not visible

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a program that has custom widgets which can be dragged and dropped from one list into another. The custom widgets are forms (label/lineedit). The code below has most of that functionality, but whenever I drag and drop an item, it creates the space for it but the contents of the widget cant be seen. I've tried playing around with the setdropmode() function but that hasn't helped.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QListWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QListWidgetItem, \
    QHBoxLayout, QAbstractItemView
import os
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap, QColor, QBrush, QFontDatabase, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QSize, Qt, QThread, QProcess

class CustomQWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        # formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(139, 69, 291, 131))
        formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(formLayoutWidget)
        formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")

        lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(formLayoutWidget)
        lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, lineEdit)

        lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(formLayoutWidget)
        lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, lineEdit_2)

        lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(formLayoutWidget)
        lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, lineEdit_3)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(formLayoutWidget)
        label.setObjectName("label")
        label.setText("TextLabel")
        formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, label)

        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(formLayoutWidget)
        label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        label_2.setText("TextLabel")
        formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, label_2)

        label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(formLayoutWidget)
        label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        label_3.setText("TextLabel")
        formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, label_3)

        self.setLayout(formLayout)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.myListWidget1 = QListWidget()
        # self.myListWidget1.setViewMode(QListWidget.IconMode)

        self.myListWidget2 = QListWidget()
        self.myListWidget2.setViewMode(QListWidget.IconMode)
        self.myListWidget1.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.myListWidget1.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.myListWidget2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.myListWidget2.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.myListWidget2.setGridSize( QSize( 130, 130 ) )
        self.myListWidget2.setMovement(2)
        self.setGeometry(300, 350, 990, 970)
        self.myLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.myLayout.addWidget(self.myListWidget1)
        self.myLayout.addWidget(self.myListWidget2)

        self.setFixedSize(self.size())

        self.item = QListWidgetItem(self.myListWidget1)
        self.item_widget = CustomQWidget()
        self.item.setSizeHint(self.item_widget.sizeHint())
        self.myListWidget1.addItem(self.item)
        self.myListWidget1.setItemWidget(self.item, self.item_widget)

        self.item2 = QListWidgetItem(self.myListWidget1)
        self.item_widget2 = CustomQWidget()
        self.item2.setSizeHint(self.item_widget2.sizeHint())
        self.myListWidget1.addItem(self.item2)
        self.myListWidget1.setItemWidget(self.item2, self.item_widget2)
        self.myListWidget1.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)

        self.setWindowTitle('Drag and Drop Example');
        self.setLayout(self.myLayout)

        self.show()

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the dragEnterEvent and dropEvent on your widget.

```
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event: QDragEnterEvent) -> None:
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event: QDropEvent) -> None:
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
```

Comment: How do I implement those events into my code? I'm new with UI so I have no idea what I'm doing.